# Mathematical Documentaries

Tags: soft-question

Do you know of any documentaries Like Fermat's last theorem or N is number? Story of a mathematician or a theorem.Dont know if this is a good site for the question.

Comment: Have you asked Google about your question?

Comment: If I understand well your question, there are many sources,some quite attractive,  but, to my knowledge, they are very scattered.

Comment: [_Chaos: A Mathematical Adventure_](http://www.chaos-math.org/) (2010) and [_Dimensions_](http://www.dimensions-math.org/) (2008) by Jos Leys, Étienne Ghys, Aurélien Alvarez, et al. are excellent, [CC BY-NC-ND 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/3.0/deed.en)-licensed (i.e., free) movies about math.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Mathematics in Movies](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/mathmovies/).